# ASP.NET Schema Tables Causing Issues in VSTS

Tags: asp.net, gdr

After installing the VSTS Database GDR and importing a SQL Server 2005 database that includes the ASP.NET provider schema tables, I get the following warnings:

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].[name].

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_AnyDataInTables] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].[type].

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].[type].

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_AnyDataInTables] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].

TSD04151: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_AnyDataInTables] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].[name].

Does anyone know how to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure, but a quick look seems to reveal the following.
The offending line in the script seems to be:

Line 42 in procedure [dbo].[aspnet_Users_DeleteUser]  <strike>(how do you do underscores here?)</strike> *(like this: \_ )*

(EXISTS (SELECT name FROM **sysobjects** WHERE (name = N'vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers') AND (type = 'V'))))

the system view sysobjects belongs to the built in system schema 'sys' which is not included in the database project. As a result the database project parser thinks (wrongly) that the reference is unresolved.

I don't think there is anything you can do but select to ignore the warning from the project settings. (Be aware that that will hide real errors from you as well.) I would probably just ignore the warnings.

**Update:**
Try to add a reference to:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\2008\DBSchemas\master.dbschema

Comment: Adding the reference did the trick.  One thing to note, since I'm targeting a SQL 2005 database, I referenced the following:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\2005\DBSchemas\master.dbschema

Comment: Thanks! It also works for VS2010 and SQL2008. 
The right folder there is (for x64 systems):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\2008

Comment: What kind of reference should I add for this file? The only one that I could add is to an XSD file, without effect (no reference was added to database project). Thanks!

Comment: Ignore my question, it was a Database reference =D.

Answer (score 3):

Kim's answer above works perfectly for the situation I asked for.  But, I also found out that you can filter the build warnings per file.  Look at http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2009/01/11/file-level-build-warning-suppression-in-the-gdr.aspx

Comment: Yes, but this is a helpful warning. Suppressing it is not an ideal solution.