# Unresolved references in Microsoft Visual Studio SQL Database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project, gdr

I have a MS DataBase project in Visual Studio.

After doing a Schema Comparison, I am trying to generate a deploy script.

The problem is I get hundreds of Unresolved references errors,such as the following two:

```
Error   385 TSD03006: View: [auditing].[AuditedEntities] has an unresolved
reference to object [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS].

Error   387 TSD03006: View: [auditing].[AuditedEntities] contains an unresolved
reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is
ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects:
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS].[C]::[CONSTRAINT_NAME],
[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS].[CONSTRAINT_NAME]
or [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS].[C]::[CONSTRAINT_NAME].
```

The SPROCS never have issues when they run.

Is there a quick and dirty way to fix this?

Perhaps even by turning off referential integrity checks perhaps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I added a reference to the master database to resolve this error, which can be achieved through the following steps.

1. Right click References under your database project
2. Click `Add Database Reference...`
3. Click the `Database project schema (.dbschema) radio button
4. Browse to the

   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VSTSDB\Extensions\SqlServer\2008\DBSchemas\master.dbschema
5. Click OK

The following question is related. [ASP.NET Schema Tables Causing Issues in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331702/asp-net-schema-tables-causing-issues-in-vsts)

Comment: This answer did not work for my environment (VS 2013); the path described did not exist. The answer by stakx worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

Your database project is missing a reference to the `master` database.

Assuming that you are talking about a [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) database project, you can add the missing reference as follows:

1. In *Solution Explorer*, open the context menu on the *References* node and select *Add Database Reference…* from it:

   [image: Add database reference via Solution Explorer]
2. In the upper portion of the opening dialog window, select the *System database* option and choose `master` from the dropdown list.

   [image: Select the System database <code>master</code>]
3. Finally, press the *OK* button. The database reference should now be added to your project.

Comment: This works. The same answer is given by Microsoft here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/787152/ssdt-intellisense-does-not-recognize-system-extended-procedures-like-sp-executesql-or-sp-xml-preparedocument

Comment: what if the reference is to another existing database which has its own project outside the solution ? If I add reference as a .dacpac, will the another database updated as well ?

Comment: @Muflix: I suggest you post this as a separate question.